# Missing contect after PHP Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, php, css

After **PHP upgrade** site got fatal error, which led to be icon v extension missing in on the server so after adding this now pages is missing footer and not displaying products properly? s our page is kiernans.ie anyone have any ideas what it could be?

**Code:** Call to undefined function mb_substr() in `/home/foodpack/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme281k/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` on line 136

Comment: What is your current PHP version in the server that you recently upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb-substr) is a multibyte-safe version of [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr), meaning it works with *characters* as opposed to *bytes*. This is most noticeable in UTF-8, where many characters are represented by two or more bytes.

According to the [installation instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php), `mbstring` is not a built-in extension. You must enable it by having the appropriate files and configuring PHP correctly. Some information can be found in the link provided, your webhost should be able to help you with the rest.

Find PHP function `mb_substr()` in your

**/home/foodpack/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme281k/template/catalog/product/list.phtml**

Throw this into a terminal:

```
php -m | grep mb
```

If `mbstring` shows up then it should work.

Look in your **php.ini** file. Search for **extension=** and look through the list of extensions. If there is one with the name **mbstring** in it then the extension should be installed. If the line is commented out (has a ; in-front of it) then it is not enabled... remove the `;`

**Restart Apache (or whatever server you are using).**